# .net assemblies

Tags: .net, xml

What are Xml serialization assembilies and why do we need them? If at all possible can you provide links?

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [XML Serializer Generator Tool (Sgen.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240(VS.80).aspx):

> The XML Serializer Generator creates
>   an XML serialization assembly for
>   types in a specified assembly ***in
>   order to improve the startup
>   performance of a XmlSerializer when it
>   serializes or deserializes objects of
>   the specified types.***

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are asking for this reference - [XML Serializer Generator Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

From Googling, I found the answer on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240%28VS.80%29.aspx).

**XML Serializer Generator Tool (Sgen.exe)**

The XML Serializer Generator creates an *XML serialization assembly* for types in a specified assembly in order to improve the startup performance of a XmlSerializer when it serializes or deserializes objects of the specified types.

**Examples**

The following command creates an assembly named Data.XmlSerializers.dll for serializing all the types contained in the assembly named Data.dll.

```
sgen Data.dll
```

The Data.XmlSerializers.dll assembly can be referenced from code that needs to serialize and deserialize the types in Data.dll.

---

So in summary, you only need them if you are using Xml Serialization a lot and you want to get better performance.